# Solution for $x = -c_1  e ^ x + c_2  e ^{-x}$

Tags: calculus

How can I solve this equation,
$$x = -c_1 e ^ x + c_2e ^{-x}, \;\;\; 0 < c_1, c_2 < 1$$
We can use $t = e^x$ which will result in,
$$t \ln(t) + c_1 t ^ 2 - c_2 = 0, \;\;\; 0 < c_1, c_2 < 1$$
but how can I solve this one then?

Comment: That doesn't have the look of something with an analytical solution. Use Newton-Raphson or something like it.

Comment: Ummm, I already did it. I am just wondered if it can be solved analytically or not.

Comment: @Mohsen: Highly unlikely. If $c_1=0$ or $c_2=0$, then you need Lambert's W function, having both nonzero is only going to make it more difficult. It is equivalent to $xe^x = -c_1(e^2)^x + c_2$.

Comment: @Arturo: You are right. Actually, I was solving a system of equations containing two Lambert's W functions. I simplified the equations and got the one I posted here.

Comment: @Mohsen: Yeah, if you have a system of transcendental equations, the likelihood of obtaining an analytical solution is rather tiny. On the other hand, I'd rather do Newton-Raphson on a system with exponentials than a system with Lambert functions.

Comment: @J. M.:  I was thinking about the same issue :) Is there any reason not to apply Newton-Raphson to the Lambert function?

Comment: Well, algorithms to compute the Lambert function use Newton-Raphson (or variants thereof) to begin with... so I'd say the Lambert function would be more expensive to compute than an exponential.

Comment: You wrote $-c1$. Do you have any assumptions on these parameters (namely, positivity)?

Comment: @Gortaur: I did edit the question and added a constraint. Both $c_1$ and $c_2$ must be in the range (0, 1). Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Let's find first derivative of the both sides of the equation:

$x'=(-C_1e^x)'+(C_2e^{-x})'$

$1=-C_1e^x -  C_2e^{-x}$ and now let's find first derivative of the left and right side:

$(1)'=(-C_1e^x)' -  (C_2e^{-x})'$

$0=-C_1e^x + C_2e^{-x} \Rightarrow C_1e^x=C_2e^{-x}$ , which means that:

$x=-C_1e^x + C_1e^x$

$x=0$

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but surely for $c_1\not= c_2$ $x=0$ is not a solution?

Comment: $x=0$ would be right if $c_1$ and $c_2$ were the same, but your method is not a proper method for a general solution. Differentiation "loses" constants...

Comment: @J.M,you are right...obvious logical mistake